# How to change cell color in a listgrid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to change font and color of a specific **cell** in a ListGrid.

I succeeded to change the color of the entire **row** with the following lines, but not of a single row:

```java
for (ListGrid table : tables)
{
ListGridField[] columns = table.getFields(); 
for (Record record : table.getRecords())
    {
       ....
       record.setAttribute("cssText",
                           "font-weight:bold; font-size:80%; color:#FF3300;");
```

I don't want to use getCellCSSText function, i tried the following but it didn't work:

```java
ListGridField gridfield = table.getField(columns[1].getName());
gridfield.setAttribute("cssText", 
                       "font-weight:bold; font-size:80%; color:#FF3300;");
table.refreshFields();
```

Comment: You should accept more answers to previous questions, to increase the change of getting a good answer to this question...

Comment: I accepted answer that helped me.

Comment: If no more than 60% of the answers to your questions helped you, I think either the way you asked the questions is not right, or you just don't except the correct answers because people didn't write your code for you.

Comment: @Hiddle I'll note what you said.
Although, i don't accept my own answers!

Comment: Why you don't want to use the getCellCSSText function? It seems to me it is the nominal way to achieve your requirement.

Comment: @gpapaz I don't want to use this one because, to set the color i need an external parameter.
I have no problem using it, if there is a way to attach a value to each cell. A value that is not displayed. And not the way i did it : by hiding a column

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do it. But this is how i did it:

1. I added a hidden column to the table, that contain the color.
2. In getCellCSSText i read the color and the column name and set the color.

Is there a way to add an invisible parameter to a ListGridRecord? So that i won't add an entire column.